# Spresense Arduino ソフトウェアシリアル 通信速度について

Tags: spresense, arduino, シリアル通信

Spresenseを使用してArduino-IDE環境にてプログラムを作っています。
Spresenseをソフトウェアシリアルにて、電圧レベル変換を通してESP32のWifi機能をATコマンドモードにて操作しています。

**質問**
通信速度を上げるとデータが化ける場合があります。

[2.17. Software Serial ライブラリ | Spresense Arduino 開発ガイド](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_software_serial_%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA)

上記の開発ガイドでは、通信速度が「最大の転送レートは 250,000bps」とあります。
しかし、速度が19,200bps程度までしかうまく通信ができず、38,400bpsなどではデータが化けてしまいます。
同じ構成でハードウェアシリアルでは115,200bpsなどでもうまく動作できているのですが実際の構成(LTE拡張)では使えません。
ソフトウェアシリアルはRXとTXにD9,D3を使用しています。
一般のArduinoでもあまり速度は上げられないようですが、spresenseも同じなのでしょうか。
250,000bpsとまでは言いませんが、何か改善する方法が無いのでしょうか。

**読み込み部コード**

```
SoftwareSerial  wifi_serial(9, 3);
wifi_serial.begin(38400);
while(1){
  if (wifi_serial.available()){
    Serial.write(wifi_serial.read());
  }
}
```

**開発環境**
・spresense本体＋spresense lte拡張ボード＋ESP32
・Arduino IDE

Comment: ソフトウエアシリアルは 19200bps で受信できれば御の字（送信のみならマニュアルで歌っている 250000bps もできるだろうが）まあ常識的に無理っス

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。SPRESENSEは一般のArduinoとは違うと考えてここまで高速なのかと思い、公開されている情報から他の部品の構成を行ったのですが、1/10ほどの速度は辛い…